# Suppose f is continuous on [a, b], to find f(c)=c

Tags: functions, continuity

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(x）∈ [a,b]$ for any $x ∈ [a,b]$. Show that there exists a $c ∈ [a,b]$ such that $ f(c) = c$.

I know that according to theorem IVT, for any $c ∈ (a,b)$ there exists a $X_0$ such that $f(X_0) = c$. Then how to prove that $X_0 = c$ ?
Or my thought was wrong?

Comment: Imaging a rectangle in Cartesian coordinate system where $x \in [a, b]$ and $y = f(x) \in [a, b]$ touches the max and min 
I doubt if this $f(c) = c$ will be always true

Comment: Apply IVT to $f(x)-x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Then by IVT. There exist $c\in (a,b)$ such that $g(c)=0$ which implies $f(c)=c$.

Comment: thanks！it helps a lot